# In India, consent based on a misunderstanding of the facts is not considered valid (S. 90 of the Penal Code). How widely can this rule be applied?

Tags: india, indian-penal-code

[Section 90](https://www.indiacode.nic.in/show-data?actid=AC_CEN_5_23_00037_186045_1523266765688&orderno=94) of the Indian Penal Code says:

> Consent known to be given under fear or misconception.
>
> A consent is not such a consent as is intended by any section of this Code, if the consent is given by a person under fear of injury, or under a misconception of fact, and if the person doing the act knows, or has reason to believe, that the consent was given in consequence of such fear or misconception...

Can this interpretation of obtaining sexual consent through a promise of marriage be applied broadly, such as in cases of non-payment of dues to sex workers or someone breaking their promise to not cheat in exchange for sex from their partner?

Would there be any issues with such a judicial interpretation?

Comment: This would be improved by rewriting to clarify just what siutuations the OP has in mind. As written it is not very clear in my view.

Comment: Is there an example of a promise of marriage case? Usually a misconception of fact and a broken promise are different things unless there was an intent not to perform the promise at the outset.

Comment: @ohwilleke surely false promises of marriage are a common ruse, albeit difficult to establish in court.  But difficult is not the same as impossible.  I certainly don't know of any case, but I can imagine that someone bragging about a sexual encounter might reveal the intention to break the promise and that such bragging might be admissible.